# How to restore plesk files correctly?

Tags: web-hosting, webserver, plesk

Recently my server crashed. So I reinstalled Plesk and uploaded all databases to `var/lib/mysql` and site files to `backup/vhosts`.

How do I get it all back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

you can directly restore your Plesk backup using the backup sections and all your files and databases will get restored automatically.

In case the automatic backup restoring fails, just create the site and databases manually, copy the files via FTP or File manager and import the databases via PhpMyadmin tool.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few workarounds for manually accessing the file.

Plesk has an outline on a few advanced methods in an article from their Knowledge Base.
If you are on a Mac, the third-party "Stuffit" application is capable of reading these files. They offer a free version with basic functionality. There is a Windows version of Stuffit as well, however, it does not provide the same functionality.
Using Stuffit Expander to access your Plesk-generated backups manually

Download and install Stuffit Expander from their website.
Create your backup in Plesk and download to your Mac.
Right-click on the backup file and select Open With > Other.
Select Stuffit Expander from the application list.
You should now see your extracted directory. You will see a list of your domain directories.
Repeat the steps for each directory, such as httpdocs.
You should now be able to see all your files, and just restore the ones you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should have applied your last server backup to restore everything. Now you need temporarily remove all files you uploaded previously, create databases and sites from Plesk panel (or from command line) and then upload files back.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you just to upload your files via FTP and restore your database backup by means of Phpmyadmin.

If you previously created your Plesk backup, just use the toll to restore the backup via the Plesk backup section.